# To remove \n but not \n\n

Tags: regular-expression, perl

Data

```
23. Lorem
A) he
B) ha
C) hu
c

2. Ipsun yes right to write something here?
A) Ok
B) No 
C) yes
b

292. Ipsun
A) Apex
B) hello
b

289. He
A) hu
B) Ha
C) He
The right answer is:
1) Ab
2) Abc
3) Ac
2
```

where the replacement should return to meet Quizlet.com's syntax requirements

```
23. Lorem A) he B) ha C) hu
c    
2. Ipsun yes right to write something here? A) Ok B) No C) yes 
b
292. Ipsun A) Apex B) hello
b
289. He A) hu B) Ha C) He The right answer is: 1) Ab 2) Abc 3) Ac
2
```

This removes all empty spaces, `s/\n//g` in Vim.

**How can you remove all \n but not \n\n in Perl or Vim?**
I think there is a need for *Look-ahead* because you cannot replace before you know that there is no second \n.

Comment: It's probably easier to understand and implement if you perform it in three steps; replace \n\n by some unused [control] character (say \a), then delete all \n, and finally replace the \a by \n\n again. (Define a vim macro if you need that replacement often.)

Comment: @Janis Please, make your comment an answer so we can consider it.

Comment: Why you ask for "not \n\n" because sample formatting do by different action?

Comment: @Masi, I'm new here, so I don't understand why (presuming the hint is of some use) you cannot consider it if brought to you as a comment. (Shall I really copy/paste the comment into an answer?)

Comment: @Janis You can make an answer where you give examples what you mean if you. It so much easier to read things in answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

New GNU sed (with parameter -z) do it one pass:

```
sed -z 's/\n\(\n\|[A-Z0-9][)a-z]\)/ \1/g' DATA
```

Comment: Awesome! I love GNU. So much better manual than in BSD Sed. What else has changed in GNU sed compared to BSD Sed? Any review article about GNU Sed?

Comment: @Masi The `sed` parameters have read from man pages. To my regred I can't compare because I havn't BSD.

Answer (score 1):

Using `awk` + `sed` perhaps? For:

```
$ cat quiz 
23. Lorem
A) he
B) ha
C) hu
c

2. Ipsun yes right to write something here?
A) Ok
B) No 
C) yes
b
```

Run

```
$ awk NF=NF RS= OFS=' ' quiz | sed 's/\([a-z]$\)/\n\1/' 

23. Lorem A) he B) ha C) hu 
c
2. Ipsun yes right to write something here? A) Ok B) No C) yes 
b
```

Comment: I get at the beginning of each answer the letter "n" like hu \n nc. My OS is OS X Yosemite which may be the reason: awk version 20070501, sed which manual updated 2015.

Answer (score 1):

I like playing with regular expressions but truly I don't feel like I am a master of it. I would do what you want in 2 steps:

```
$ perl -i.bak -0pe  's/\n([A-Z])/ \1/g' DATA
$ less DATA
23. Lorem A) he B) ha C) hu
c

2. Ipsun yes right to write something here? A) Ok B) No  C) yes
b
```

And now just remove empty lines, for example with `sed` or `flush-lines` function in Emacs:

```
$ sed '/^$/d' -i DATA
$ less DATA
23. Lorem A) he B) ha C) hu
c
2. Ipsun yes right to write something here? A) Ok B) No  C) yes
b
```

Or just press `:` in Vim and paste this: `/^$/d`.

**EDIT:**

```
$ perl -i.bak -0pe 's/\n([A-Z0-9]\))/ \1/g' DATA
```

Comment: How can you save this data? Running sed '/^$/d' -i DATA gives STOUT but running [command] > 2 does not save it to the file 2. There are some quotes which you can put around the STOUT command and then store it but I cannot remember which ones.

Comment: Your `sed` probably does not `--in-place` option. Try this: `cat DATA | sed '/^$/d'  > <FILE>`. Check `man sed` what `-i` option does for you.

Comment: Or just press `:` in Vim and paste this: `/^$/d`.

Comment: I added more example data to the body. Your command breaks in the last two examples. I think this \n([A-Z] should be \n([A-Z0-9]

Comment: This my new command \n[A-Z0-9] will put one empty space before each new question. What do you get?

Comment: I also get a space before each question using command you suggested.

Comment: How can you not get it? How can this empty space come?

Comment: Well, I said I *DO* get an empty space before each question

Comment: @Masi: see updated answer. I am not sure about the last question though. In `289. He A) hu B) Ha C) He The right answer is: 1) Ab 2) Abc 3) Ac` shouldn't `The right answer ...` start in new line?

Answer (score 1):

(Edited solution due to feedback about actual requirements...)

It's probably easier to understand and implement if you perform it in four steps; replace \n\n by some unused [control] character (say \a), add an \a at the front of a line with an \a, then delete all \n, and finally replace the \a by \n again. (Define a vim macro if you need that replacement often.)

In vim (ex.mode) for example:

```
:%s/\n\n/^A/
:g/^A/s/^/^A/
:%s/\n/ /g
:%s/^A/^M/g
```

where `^A` is created by `<ctrl>-V <ctrl>-A`, and `^M` is created by `<ctrl>-V <Enter>`.

Comment: Good idea but there is a bug in this line ":%s/\n//g". You will get the answer, which is at the last line, together with the last option. Like "huc". Costas' regex can probably be written in Vim too.

Comment: Masi, I don't understand what you are saying here ("last option"? "huc"?). I tested the ex commands and they seem to work fine; they keep the empty line (\n\n) intact and put all other lines (\n) together. Wasn't that what you actually needed?

Comment: Please, see the body of my question again. There is the wanted output. This command does not return it. "Last option" = "B) hello" in Question 292, for instance. "huc" got for Question 23 "hu + c" = [last option] + [answer].

Comment: Masi, two hours before your last comment I edited my answer. My previous answer solved what you described in your subject line, which was not what you wanted. Though the actual version solves your sample input/output you posted (assuming only that after each block of questions, also after the last one, is an empty line).

Answer (score 0):

The syntax for a [negative lookahead in vim](https://www.inputoutput.io/lookbehind-lookahead-regex-in-vim/) is like this:

```
:s/\n\n\@!//gN
```

Where `N` is a number of lines.  [In perl](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html#Looking-ahead-and-looking-behind), it would be:

```
s/\n(?!\n)//
```

**However**, I think you'll find that's not exactly what you are trying to do, since in your example output, `c` and `b` are both on a line of their own.  If you replace all newlines not followed by another newline, they will be concatenated onto the previous lines, i.e. you will have:

```
23. LoremA) heB) haC) huc
2. Ipsun yes right to write something here?A) OkB) No C) yesb
```

Comment: Yes, this is not not what I want. I want the output as described in the end of my body i.e. the answer should on the separate line.